# PHP: How can copy($url, $filename) work with %-encoding for UTF-8 characters?

Tags: php, copy, mp3

How come this works

```
copy("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Love+Me", "/directory/loveme.mp3");
```

But this doesn't?

```
copy("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=hi&q=%26%232310%3B%26%232354%3B%26%232370%3B+%26%232327%3B%26%232379%3B%26%232349%3B%26%232368%3B",  "/directory/loveme.mp3");
```

If I paste both URLs into a browser, they both play fine.  But the 2nd URL just copies a blank mp3 file, while the first one copies the correct MP3 file.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this on the URL before calling `copy`:

```
function utf8RawUrlDecode ($source) {
    $decodedStr = "";
    $pos = 0;
    $len = strlen ($source);
    while ($pos < $len) {
        $charAt = substr ($source, $pos, 1);
        if ($charAt == '%') {
            $pos++;
            $charAt = substr ($source, $pos, 1);
            if ($charAt == 'u') {
                // we got a unicode character
                $pos++;
                $unicodeHexVal = substr ($source, $pos, 4);
                $unicode = hexdec ($unicodeHexVal);
                $entity = "&#". $unicode . ';';
                $decodedStr .= utf8_encode ($entity);
                $pos += 4;
            }
            else {
                // we have an escaped ascii character
                $hexVal = substr ($source, $pos, 2);
                $decodedStr .= chr (hexdec ($hexVal));
                $pos += 2;
            }
        } else {
            $decodedStr .= $charAt;
            $pos++;
        }
    }
    return $decodedStr;
}
```

I got this from the comments on the [docs for `rawurldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) -- scroll way down.